# In Oracle, what is the difference between a hash join and a sort-merge join?

Tags: oracle, join

In Oracle, I can use the hints `USE_HASH` or `USE_MERGE` to instruct the optimizer to do a hash join or a sort-merge join.  How are those types of joins different and when/why should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 5):

Jonathan Lewis posted a really good explanation of how hash joins and merge joins work:

- Hash Joins - http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/joins-hj/
- Merge Joins - http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/joins-mj/

and for good measure...

- Nested Loop Joins - http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/joins-nlj/

Answer (score 3):

"when/why should I use one or the other"

Generally you shouldn't worry about it. That's what the Oracle optimizer is for.

Comment: I would agree that generally I shouldn't worry about it.  Would there be any times that I should worry about it?

Comment: @Matthew: just like all hints, they are part of a strategy to adjust for conditions when the optimizer cannot find the optimal plan for a query (e.g. when you know more about the data then it does). They should be used sparingly because they limit the optimizer's choices.

Answer (score 2):

The `use_hash` hint requests a hash join against the specified tables. A hash join loads the rows from the left hand table into an in-memory hash table.

The `use_merge` hint forces a sort/merge operation that essentially does a full table scan and creates a traditional index on the fly.  I.e., A to Z.

Because of the memory restrictions on hash joins, you want to use them, generally, only on smaller left hand tables

Sort merge joins are generally best for queries that produce very large result sets or tables that do not possess indexes on the join keys.